# Find and Replace using Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am stuck to write a Batch script for the following task.
Say I have the following text files.

**A.txt**

```
hello world-0
hi ABC

hello world-1
hi ABC

hello world-2
hi ABC
```

**B.txt**

```
CAT
MAT
RAT
```

My **output.txt** file should contain

```
hello world-0
hi CAT

hello world-1
hi MAT

hello world-2
hi RAT
```

How can I achieve this using Batch script?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem Read a.txt with findstr /n to avoid blank line removal
rem Read b.txt with set /p only when a replacement is needed

< "b.txt" (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%f in ('findstr /n "^" ^<"a.txt"') do (
        set "line=%%g"
        if defined line if not "!line: ABC=!"=="!line!" (
            set /p "repl="
            for /f %%r in ("!repl!") do set "line=!line: ABC= %%r!"
        )
        echo(!line!
    )
)

endlocal
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Use a good file parsing tool such as `awk`. you can download awk [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm%E2%80%8E)

```
C:\>awk "FNR==NR{a[++c]=$1;next}{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i==\"ABC\") { $i=a[++d] } }  }1" B.txt A.txt
hello world-0
hi CAT

hello world-1
hi MAT

hello world-2
hi RAT
```